# In Kyrie Eleison, what does "derramo aos teus pes minha vida" mean?

Tags: português-brasileiro

I would like to ask a question on the Portuguese version of the hymn Kyrie Eleison.

Most of the lyrics I could figure out their meanings,
but I had no clues with the following part:

> Como a pecadora caida, derramo aos teus pes minha vida

"Como a pecadora caida" means "Just like an injured sinner", right?

But what does the rest mean? I couldn't 
even find the word "pes" in my dictionary.

I looked it up with google and the google 
returned "foot"... Again, I have no idea. Or is it
related to a story about cleaning feet with
water in the New Testament?

Answer (score 4):

The reason it doesn’t make sense is because you’ve miscopied the Portuguese. You cannot leave off diacritical markings because those are lexically significant in Portuguese — and, for that matter, in virtually all other languages that regularly use them.

English speakers aren’t used to the idea that this means it normally  spells a different word if it has a different diacritic. (One exception to that principle is that Brazil and Portugal do not use the same vowel in words like the paired spellings *econômico, económico* respectively.)

With the corrected text, it becomes clearer to non-native speakers who aren’t used to “hearing” the rightly written words in their minds no matter how they’ve been miswritten on the page:

- Como a pecadora ca**í**da, derramo aos teus p**é**s minha vida.
  Vê as lágrimas do meu coração e salva-me!

So roughly something like:

- Like the fallen sinner, I pour out my life at your feet.
  See the tears of my heart and save me.

*Derramar* is to spill or pour (out). *Salvar* is save as in souls not save as in banking or save as in computer files.

This is using the second-person singular (corresponding to the pronoun *tu*) verb forms that were historically customary when addressing the deity because they are intimate forms, as to a close personal friend. Those forms are still used for your friends in Portugal, but in Brazil they aren’t used by most of the country, having been supplanted by third-person forms (corresponding to the pronoun *você*).

I don’t know where those non-Greek lines are from. In [the Latin liturgy of the Roman rite, the Kyrie](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyrie_eleison) has always just been the two Greek lines:

> 1. Kyrie, eleïson.
>      Κύριε, ἐλέησον.
>      Senhor, tende piedade (de nós).
>      (O) Lord, have mercy (on us).
> 2. Christe, eleïson.
>      Χριστέ, ἐλέησον.
>      Criste, tende piedade (de nós).
>      (O) Christ, have mercy (on us).

Note that grammatically the *tende* there is a second person plural verb form, so corresponds to the archaic pronoun *vós* not to *tu*. Normally the imperative for *ter* is just *tem tu* in the second person singular, or else *tenha você* in the third person singular. That *tende vós* form used there is a very formal form, plural in construction but here singular in sense as one might reverentially address a king or pope.

It’s an archaic form essentially unused today save in a few places in the north of Portugal, but remains familiar just as saying things like *thou art thine own master* still are recognizable to native speakers of English but which remains productive only in a few places in the north of England.

---

In case anyone is interested in how to spell and say *Kyrie eleison* in English, it turns out that there’s a lot of latitude in that regard. The OED says that it was once also spelled *eleyson* or *elison* historically, and that even now the *eleëson* spelling still exists contemporaneously. It has this etymological note on the origin of the Romanizations and pronunciations in English:

> The Greek words *Κύριε ἐλέησον* ‘Lord, have mercy’, occurring in the 
>   Greek text of  *Ps.* cxxii. 3,  *Matt.* xv. 22, xvii. 15, 
>   etc. The Greek words were written in Latin *kyrie* (medieval Latin
>   also *kirie*), and (by itacism of η) *eleison*. As in other
>   Christian words (e.g. Maria, Sophia, Helena, Jacobus, etc.), the Greek
>   accent was retained, giving *eˈleīson*, later *eˈlēison*, or
>   *eˈleison*. Since the Renaissance, some have represented the Greek
>   more literally and quantitatively by *eleˈēson*. Hence many
>   varieties of pronunciation in English, some retaining the medieval Latin
>   (which is also modern Greek) given above, some following the school
>   pronunciation of ancient Greek or Latin, or with various English
>   modifications of the vowels, as /ˈkɪrɪeɪ/,  /ˈkaɪrɪiː/,  /ˈkaɪrɪ/,
>   /ɪˈliːɪsɒn/,  /ɛlɪˈiːsɒn/,  /ɛlɪˈaɪsɒn/,  /ɪˈlaɪsɒn/.

I myself learned to say it as /ˈkiː.ɾi.e ͡  eˈle(j).iː.son/ when singing it in choral contexts.

Comment: Tangent: in the Galandum Galundaina song Coquelhada Marralheira they say it "Pater Noster, [Crialeson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcKBq03onGg#t=44)"... :) but it's [Mirandês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirandese_language), not Portuguese.

Comment: @ANeves outro fan do GG? Eu vou a sua terra em umas semanas para tentar de aprender o mirandês. Tchrist: only thing I might change is to point out that the *vós* forms are in fact singular, but the number of that pronoun has varied and plural now but for some niche circumstances like some prayers

Comment: @guifa I don’t understand what you mean by saying that ”the *vós* forms are in fact singular”. Using 2pl verbs for a single super-formal/revered individual doesn’t make them grammatically singular, only notionally so, like using *vous voyez* in French for someone you don't know or using *you are* for just one person in present-day English. I’m ok with calling both Latin *O vos omnes qui transitis per viam, attendite et videte* and Old Spanish *«Ya Campeador, en buena çinxiestes espada! ⋯ Çid, en el nuestro mal vos non ganades nada»* uses of plural *vos* **verbs** but #2 is for just one person.

Comment: tchrist: What I meant to say is that calling *vós* forms (pronouns/verbs) plural-used-as-singular when for the history of Portuguese it's been used as both (*vos* was both even in later Latin) seems a bit off.  Maybe I'm being a bit pedantic (okay, a lot), but I'd just say "tende is the vós form which nowadays is generally used for plural".  I only protest because your answers tend to be so detailed-focused :-)

Comment: @guifa Portuguese *vós* forms aren't generally used at all, let alone for plurals. :)

Comment: @tchrist I guess I sometimes have to remember that my view of the language is distorted since I spend all my time in central and north Portugal :-)

Comment: @tchrist Hey, amigo (or amiga? I heard that I should be very careful about this usage...)! Thanks for the explanation. I just figured out why I couldn't find pes in my dictionary; it's the plural of pe. pe means foot? Who could have thought about that. About the Kyrie Eleison, I would just take it for granted ;-) And, I just don't know how to put diacritical markings. Seems I need new PC for that.

Comment: @NJS No, *pe* does not mean foot in Portuguese, and *pes* does not mean feet either. The singular is *pê* and the plural is *pês*. Think of letters with diacritics as creating completely different words than the same letters without them, because that's how it works. You can always use the mouse to copy and paste, but really you should learn the right entry modes.

Comment: @tchrist I might want to ask questions mainly about songs in future too. So, let me ask now. Is there any way I can type diacritics?

Comment: @NJS Why of course there is. But I'm sure you're using a different system than I myself am, whether that's a palmtop cell phone computer or some shared terminal at a public library or your university's supercomputer. So you will have to find that out.  I bet we have Stack Exchange sites that are oriented towards these matters. :)

Comment: @NJS the singular is **pé** (e with acute accent), the plural **pés**. tchrist made a small typo with the circumflex. :) Pê (with circumflex accent) is the name of the letter p, and "pês" are several p letters. I guess this proves the point he was making, that the diacritical marks are *that* important...